# nginx config file not working even though I copied the template

Tags: nginx

I looked around at other examples and tried to replicate a very basic nginx server layout. However, it's not working at all (other than example.com, which correctly redirects to index.html).

Here's my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /draw/ {
        root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/projects/draw;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /drawsomething.html;
    }
    location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
        root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/pic;
    }
}
```

Basically, I store everything in `/templates/`. I want to make it so when someone goes to `example.com/draw` it displays `drawsomething.html`, which is in `/var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/projects/draw`. I followed the example on the website and it doesn't seem to be working. The redirect for images seems to be working, though. Also, what if I want to include script files? Could I just use:

```
location ~ \.js$ {
    root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/script;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the trailing slash :

```
location /draw {
        root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/projects/draw;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /drawsomething.html;
}
```

eventually you can add an index file :

```
location /draw {
        root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/projects/draw;
        index drawsomething.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
}
```

Comment: I currently have `root /var/www/example.com/public_html/templates/projects/draw;` and `index drawsomething.html;` inside of the `location /draw {...}` block and it isn't working. Do I absolutely need to use `try_files`?

Comment: What is not working ? Here if there is images, the last location block will match before the /draw location block. Maybe it's what is not working !?

Comment: It's returning 500: internal server error when I attempt to go to example.com/draw. I did `sudo service nginx restart` after I edited the config file.

Comment: Here's a link to my [current config file setup](http://pastebin.com/B4L2qZMB).

Comment: I did put "@backend" in the try_files as an example since it seems logical you have one. Firstly remove it, then add "error_log /path/to/error.log" and see what error nginx report.

Comment: @Luxelin Did you try testing the `nginx.conf` configuration with `sudo nginx -t`?

Comment: @Paul he has a 500 error which means nginx starts and answer, so the conf is ok.